# access to xml of fragments in Tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I created an app on AS and I use Tab Layout with View Pager, Fragment in it from  [this](http://alexzh.com/tutorials/tablayout-android-design-support-library/) site!

and I want to access each fragment layout (I have 3 fragment) to apply some changes on them. I searched about it in the Internet but I could not find anything about it.

Comment: Try to provide some code or specific problems in your question.. very hard to help without it

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code or errors.. I'll try to give the best answer I can.. In the class you set up the tab layout you can create the page fragments like so:

```
public class TabLayoutActivity extends MainActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    this.addPages(vp);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vp);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(listener(vp));
}

//ADD ALL PAGES
private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
    MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Tab1Fragment tab1Fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
    adapter.addPage(mondayFragment);
    Tab2Fragment tab2Fragment = new Tab2Fragment();
    adapter.addPage(tab2Fragment);
    Tab3Fragment tab3Fragment = new Tab3Fragment();
    adapter.addPage(tab3Fragment);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener listener(final ViewPager pager) {
    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}
}
```

You then create 3 classes, Tab1Fragment, Tab2Fragment, and Tab3Fragment, aswell as the xml layouts for each. Here is an example of one of the tab fragment classes:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, null);

          }
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Tab 1";
}
}
```

This is a very simple example to give you an idea. You can then change the xml layout in the corresponding fragment class. Let me know if you have any questions